# Creating div element with a for Loop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

This is a really simple question but I don't know why it doesn't work. I have an array with 4 items inside. And I have a container which I would like to insert a number of divs based on the number of items in my array. I used a for loop for this but it is only creating one div. Should it not create 4 of the same div elements?

This is the code:

```js
count = new Array['1', '2', '3', '4'];
container = document.getElementById('items');

for (i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
  container.innerHTML += '<div id="items"></div>';
}
```

```css
#items {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="items"></div>
```

This is the link  **http://codepen.io/2bu/pen/jyxNbw**

Comment: You're misusing the array, `count` essentially has no purpose.  The only time it's used after being created is for the length, so using this array would also work with the code `count = ["this", "is", "not", "necessary"]`.

Comment: It was permanently codepen problem and some problem of your code. Look at the answer below. Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/danielnewman/0z6Ljxb2/

Answer (score 10):

The way you are creating the array is incorrect.

Try this instead:

```
var count = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
```

**Note:** Inside the `for` loop, you are creating elements that have the same ID. IDs should be unique.

Also, as mentioned you will want to append to the 'items' div instead of adding a new div with a duplicate id.

I would do something like this:

```
var count = ['1','2','3','4'];
var container = document.getElementById('items');
for(var i = 0; i < count.length; i++){
    container.append('<div>' + count[i] + '</div>');
}
```

And to improve the iteration:

```
var counts = ['1','2','3','4'];
var container = document.getElementById('items');
counts.forEach(function(count) {
    container.append('<div>' + count + '</div>');
});
```

It is rarely necessary to use `for(var i = 0; i < x; i++)`. Using `forEach`, `map` or `reduce` are considerably better (code is more concise, temporary variables are unnecessary etc.).

Answer (score 0):

1)You cannot create more DOM `elements` with same `id`.Use classes instead.

2)You have to define the array in the following way: `var count = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];`

Here is the final code:

```js
// var container = document.getElementById("container");
// for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
//    container.innerHTML += '<div class="box"></div>';
// } 
count = ['1','2','3','4'];
container = document.getElementById('itemsContainer');
  for(i = 0; i < count.length; i++){
    container.innerHTML+='<div class="items"></div>';
  }

var square= document.getElementsByClassName('items')[2];
square.style.backgroundColor='red';
```

```css
.items{
  margin-top:10px;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background:gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="itemsContainer"></div>
```

**If you want to access** one `items` DOM `element`, you have to use `document.getElementsByClassName()` method which returns a `NodeList`.

```
var square= document.getElementsByClassName('items')[2];
square.style.backgroundColor='red';
```

Comment: To make sure I understand, I have to remove ID and change it to a Class instead  and put VAR in front of my ARRAY container ?

Comment: Not quite, for the ID issue yes, but for the array issue there's something else underlying that's not right.  Arrays are a built-in type in javascript so you don't use `new` for it, you instead just use an array literal.

Comment: Ok cool so I just made the changes and I still get the same result                        http://codepen.io/2bu/pen/jyxNbw

Comment: @cord, look at my answer. In your `codepen` example there is no `element` with id `items`.

Comment: Do I have to change document.getElementById

Comment: @Alex, Thanks  I copied and passed your answer

Comment: @cord, don't forget to accept answer in order to help other people.

Comment: How would I be able to use each one as an Class / ID if I want to give [3] for example a different background color

Comment: Do you want to change the background color for three of squares ?

Comment: Yes but the bigger reasoning is the I would like to be able to STYLE each one

Comment: Yes, that's possible..i will update my answer in few seconds.

Comment: If I have some understanding of how to style one [ 3 ] for example I should be able to target each one

Comment: @Alex, Thanks for that code, I would like to get the ID  of [ 3 ] from JS and style that ID square [3] in CSS, not JS

Comment: Do you want to style every square ?

Comment: What do you mean `I would like to get the ID of [ 3 ] JS` ?